# No consigo encontrar la consulta sql adecuada

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo una consulta en la que necesito saber el numero de actualizaciones desde la ultima vez que un usuario entra en un *hilo*.

Cada vez que un usuario entra en un hilo se ejecuta la siguiente consulta:

```
INSERT INTO visita_post (`postId`, `nick`, `fecha_ultimo_acceso`) 
            VALUES(?, ?, sysdate()) 
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE fecha_ultimo_acceso = sysdate()'
```

Y se añade a la tabla `visita_post` que tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
postId                 int(11)
nick                   varchar(30)
fecha_ultimo_acceso    datatime
```

Para ver cuantas actualizaciones se han realizado desde la ultima visita ejecuto la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT  
        p.count(id) nActualizacion,p.hiloid,
        p.post_tema
        from post p, visita_post v 
        where p.post_tema = v.postId 
        and p.fecha > v.fecha_ultimo_acceso 
        and v.nick = ?
        and p.hiloid = ?
        group by p.hiloid,
        p.post_tema
```

La consulta me muestra el numero cuantos *post nuevos* hay desde la ultima vez que se ejecuto el `insert`pero esta consulta tiene varios problemas que no consigo resolver.

- Si nunca se ha ingresado en un hilo no muestra ninguna actualización pero necesito que se muestre todas las actualizaciones.
  Esta parte es un poco confusa escrita de esta manera, así que lo intentare explicar con ejemplos.

Si ejecutara la segunda consulta sin usar la tabla `visita_post` con esta consulta:

```
SELECT  count(id) nActualizacion,
        post_tema,hiloid
        from post
        where 
        hiloid is not null
        GROUP By post_tema,hiloid
```

Me data como resultado en `nActualizacion` el numero total de actualizacion que existen. Me gustaria que en el caso de que el usuario nunca haya ejecutado la primera consulta se mostraran los datos de esta.

- Si la no hay actualizaciones, necesito que me devuelva 0, en lugar de ninguna fila.

### EDICION

Ahora mismo tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT
                CASE
                    WHEN p.fecha > v.fecha_ultimo_acceso THEN v.postID
                    WHEN v.postId IS NULL THEN p.id
                END) nActualizacion,
        p.hiloid,
        p.post_tema,
        v.fecha_ultimo_acceso
FROM post p
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT *
            FROM visita_post
            WHERE nick = "testing") v
    ON p.post_tema = v.postId
    AND p.fecha > v.fecha_ultimo_acceso
WHERE p.hiloid = 27
and p.post_tema is not null

GROUP BY p.hiloid,
         p.post_tema
```

Si la ejecuto como esta ahora mismo no cuenta bien los resultados, pero ejecutandola de la misma manera añadiendole un `and p.fecha > v.fecha_ultimo_acceso` en la linea anterior al group by me muestra el resultado correctamente pero no me muestra las filas que no existen en la tabla `visita_post`.

<sub>Si necesitáis mas información acerca de la base de datos pedirla en los comentarios y la adjuntare</sub>

Comment: Para el problema de q te devuelva 0 puede usar la función ISNULL de MySQL:

    SELECT IFNULL(p.count(id), 0) nActualizacion FROM ...

Comment: @ManucoBianco al ejecutarla me da este error `execute command denied to user `

Comment: tenes q ejecutarlos con permiso de root. Mira esto es lo q encontre          
I try to grant this priviledge in root.

log in as root
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE TestMediaControl.monthavrage TO 'jeinqa'@'localhost'
flush privileges;   solo cambia tu consulta, y tu user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final la consulta que me ha dado resultado es la siguiente:

```
SELECT  
    COUNT(DISTINCT
                CASE
                    WHEN p.fecha > v.fecha_ultimo_acceso THEN v.postID
                    WHEN v.postId IS NULL THEN p.id
                END) nActualizacion,
                p.hiloid,
    p.post_tema
FROM post p LEFT JOIN visita_post v
ON p.post_tema = v.postId
and v.nick ="testing"
where p.post_tema is not null


GROUP BY p.hiloid, p.post_tema  
ORDER BY `p`.`post_tema`  DESC
```

Comment: Pero ojo, si un thread ha tenido N nuevos posts, en el `CASE` le pones a todos `v.postID` en cuyo caso a lo más habrá una actualización por thread (entendiendo que postID no es post.id sino post.post_tema)

Answer (score 0):

El nombre de tus campos es confuso. En la tabla `visita_post` guardas un `postId` pero no es el `id` en la tabla post, sino que se refiere al campo `post_tema`. Por otro lado, tienes un campo `hiloid` que debiera identificar el thread que contiene los posts.

Pero bueno, suponiendo que la relación está bien hecha y efectivamente `postId` tiene equivalencia en `post_tema`... mi respuesta es la siguiente:

Si un usuario nunca ha ingresado a un thread (post_tema) y quieres que en ese caso muestre todas las actualizaciones, debieras usar:

```
SELECT  
    count(p.id) nActualizacion,
    p.hiloid,
    p.post_tema
FROM post p LEFT JOIN visita_post v 
     ON p.post_tema = v.postId 
     AND v.nick = ?
WHERE p.hiloid = ?
  AND p.fecha >= IFNULL(v.fecha_ultimo_acceso, p.fecha)
GROUP BY p.hiloid, p.post_tema
```

De esa manera, si no hay registros en `visita_post` para ese thread y ese usuario, siempre se cumple que `p.fecha` es >= a `p.fecha` y te devolverá todos los posts en ese thread.

**EDIT** tenía puesto `p.count(id)` en vez de `count(p.id)`. Gracias por la corrección

Comment: El `p,count(id)` esta mal, debe ser `count(p.id)`

Comment: He modificado tu consulta y ya funciona

Comment: LOL, es verdad, lo hice a lo bruto, pero me alegro que te  haya funcionado. Si te sirvió, márcala como resuelta  para que alguien más que vea tu pregunta sepa que al menos una de las respuestas funcionó.